# iTunes Connect Submit For Beta App Review no option to disclose IDFA usage

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, idfa

Today I uploaded a new build from Xcode to try the new TestFlight external testing program. After I submitted the beta app for review it was rejected because of "Undeclared Use of Advertising Identifier [IDFA].

I know I'm using the IDFA for ad tracking, and I have no problem declaring that, but the TestFlight submission process has no place to declare this. When I've submitted to the real app store there were questions I answered about the IDFA, but it seems the External Testing review flow does not have the same questions. It only asked about Export Compliance then I submitted.

Tried uploaded a new build and had the same problem again. Something I'm doing wrong or bug in Apple's new flow? Anybody else seeing the same problem or worked around this?

Comment: Maybe create a new version? Or call developer relations.

Comment: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165). Perhaps you should try [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I always have the same issue. The only time it worked is when version in submission for release was the same as submission for beta.

Comment: I am now convinced this is definitely an issue on their sit. Please use the form on their site to Appeal against a rejection. You can select TestFlight there as the market so it should go to the right place. I already wrote explaining their system clearly checked for IDFA disclaimer in the AppStore submission when you're submitting to  TestFlight beta.

Comment: Looks like it's working again. Give it another shot.

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm having the same issue